# Not able to create EKS cluster using eksctl

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am using following command to create an EKS cluster :

```
eksctl create cluster --name cqpocsefkdemo --node-type t2.micro --nodes 3 --nodes-min 3 --nodes-max 5 --region us-east-1 --zones us-east-1a,us-east-1b,us-east-1c,us-east-1d,us-east-1f
```

But I am getting error that I am unable to resolve, the error looks like this:

> SDK 2022/04/15 19:20:50 DEBUG request failed with unretryable error
> https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID:
> 56fa150b-5c94-499f-be10-d9a318557f15, api error SignatureDoesNotMatch:
> Signature expired: 20220415T135049Z is now earlier than
> 20220415T143550Z (20220415T145050Z - 15 min.)
>
> Error: checking AWS STS access – cannot get role ARN for current
> session: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, https response error
> StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 56fa150b-5c94-499f-be10-d9a318557f15, api
> error SignatureDoesNotMatch: Signature expired: 20220415T135049Z is
> now earlier than 20220415T143550Z (20220415T145050Z - 15 min.)

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because the system time was not in sync, I resolved this error by going to windows setting and sync up my date and time.

Comment: Glad to see you figured things out. Please mark this answer as accepted.